# How to make an icon flash/blink, which is present in a web page

Tags: javascript, html, image

I started working on advanced java few days before(too late to start on that, I know). I am stuck with a specific task of making an icon (which is present on the task bar) blink. This blinking should happen based on a specific condition, which means that it can be achieved using `javascript`.

I have been searching for a while now but is there a way to make an icon appear and disappear every 1 second or so to bring in the blinking effect ?

Comment: If you can do it in HTML, you can do it in a JSP, therefore this has *nothing* to do with Java, JSP or (polite cough) 'advanced Java'.

Comment: Tagged adv.java because jsp, javascript, etc comes under that title.

Comment: JSP is not especially advanced, and Javascript is ***NOT*** Java.

Comment: Javascript is not java and it is a known fact. I never mentioned so anywhere. Adv. java = jsp+servlets+javascript+...,  we were taught so..

Comment: `<blink></blink>` hehe :)

Comment: Well if you can help me with the question..

Comment: The code depends on the exact effect you're going for, but probably the easiest solution is to put the icon where you want on the page using HTML and CSS, and then using the JavaScript setInterval function to change the visibility (i.e., "visible" of "hidden") every so many milliseconds.

Comment: @HartleySan: I am looking for something like that. I have the icon placed in the page. I am searching for the code that might help me in the blinking function.

Comment: @Ian: Most of the browsers(ie,chrome..) do not support <blink>. So I need something else.

Comment: http://www.john-smith.me/emulating--lt-blink-gt--using-webkit-css3-animation

Comment: @AnujBalan Haha sorry, it was a joke. It's just an old tag that used to be supported

Answer (score 5):

HTML

```
<img src='image/source' alt='blinking!' id='blinking_image' />
```

Javascript

```
var img = document.getElementById('blinking_image');

var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(img.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
        img.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }else{
        img.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}, 1000); //the 1000 here is milliseconds and determines how often the interval should be run.
```

This creates an anonymous function inside the `setInterval` that runs every 1 second (1sec == 1000milisec). To see more about setInterval [checkout the mdn here on it.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

Each time it runs it checks to see if the `img` is `hidden` or `visible` if it's hidden then it shows it if it's visible then it hides it. It does this by checking the `style.visiblity` property. Which you can learn more about [here on the mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility).

Comment: Is setInterval an inbuilt function which is already defined ?

Comment: @AnujBalan Yes, see the edited answer. I actually messed up and forgot the `window` part. `setInterval` is a function assigned to the global `window object`. Technically you don't have to do `window.setInterval` but it does make it clearer what is being called.

Answer (score 3):

Small fix

instead

```
if(img.display == 'hidden')
```

use

```
if(img.style.visibility == 'hidden')
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find opacity works better because the image is still there, which means it is still clickable if necessary.  Also you can add a clear interval to stop the flashing.

```
var mycounter = 0
interval = window.setInterval(function () {
if (img.style.opacity == '0.1') {
            img.style.opacity = '1';

            mycounter = mycounter + 1
            if (mycounter == 7) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        } else {
            img.style.opacity = '0.1';
        }
    }, 500); //the 1000 here is milliseconds and determines how often the interval
```