# How do I make an image blink on javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do i make a specific image on code.org, which is in javascript, blink, Im making a simple game where you click a ball and it moves around the screen, but i also want to make it blink so the ball disappears and comes back again, I know you can do it with texts but I have a button, that is an image and cant seen to figure it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291863/how-to-make-an-icon-flash-blink-which-is-present-in-a-web-page

Comment: Have you done anything? any code?

Comment: Yes, this is the code for the basketball and when its clicked onEvent("basketball", "click", function(event) {
  console.log("court clicked!");

 
  setPosition("basketball", randomNumber(50,280), randomNumber(50, 350));
  setText("total_score", score + 1);
  score = score + 1;
if (score == 20) {
    setScreen("winScreen");
  }
 
});

Comment: And what are `onEvent`, `setPosition`, `setText` and `setScreen`? Please edit your post and add all the code you have to it

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you probably would use CSS animations for running simple animations like blink effects and use Javascript to initiate the animation. Something like what's mentioned here should do the trick:
[Imitating a blink tag with CSS3 animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955163/imitating-a-blink-tag-with-css3-animations#16012979)

Just toggle the class to start/stop the animation.